# combine two tables with date fields into a single table without overlapping dates

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

we receive data from a legacy application for a product and the data for tables is below

```
Table 1  (KEY1, ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG)
                
'1',    'abc',  '3/2/2020 12:00:00 AM', '3/3/2020 6:01:12 PM',   'N'
'2',    'abc',  '3/3/2020  6:01:13 PM', '3/3/2020 6:01:14 PM',   'N'
'3',    'abc',  '3/3/2020  6:01:15 PM', '3/3/2020 6:01:15 PM',   'N'
'4',    'abc',  '3/3/2020  6:01:16 PM', '3/3/2020 6:01:51 PM',   'N'
'5',    'abc',  '3/3/2020  6:01:52 PM', '3/4/2020 4:28:59 PM',   'N'
'6',    'abc',  '3/4/2020  4:29:00 PM', '3/4/2020 4:31:40 PM',   'N'
'7',    'abc',  '3/4/2020  4:31:41 PM', '12/31/4712',            'Y'
'8',    'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:47:08 PM', '3/19/2020 2:50:36 PM',  'N'
'9',    'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:50:37 PM', '3/19/2020 2:56:23 PM',  'N'
'10',   'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:56:24 PM', '12/31/4712',            'Y'

Table 2  (KEY2, ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG)
'1',    'abc',  '3/3/2020 12:00:00 AM', '3/3/2020 6:01:13 PM', 'N'
'2',    'abc',  '3/3/2020 6:01:14  PM'  '3/3/2020 6:01:14 PM', 'N'
'3',    'abc',  '3/3/2020 6:01:15  PM'  '3/4/2020 4:28:59 PM', 'N'
'4',    'abc',  '3/4/2020 4:29:00  PM'  '12/31/4712',          'Y'
'5',    'bbc',  '3/4/2020 4:31:41  PM'  '3/19/2020 2:47:07 PM','N'
'6',    'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:47:08 PM'  '3/19/2020 2:50:36 PM','N'
'7',    'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:50:37 PM'  '3/20/2020 2:56:23 PM','N'
'8',    'bbc',  '3/20/2020 2:56:24 PM'  '12/31/4712',          'Y'
```

We need to create a superset of both the tables with all distinct valid_from date from both the tables and record_end_dt will automatically be 1 second less than the next record so that there wont be overlapping dates or gaps. The challenging part is to get the appropriate keys for that time frame.
Output Table should look like below. I tried union but its not working as expected. Look figure out how to achieve below.

```
Table 2  (KEY1,KEY2, ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG)

'1','NULL', 'abc', '3/2/2020 12:00:00 AM',  '3/2/2020 11:59:59 PM',   'N'
'1','1',    'abc', '3/3/2020 12:00:00 AM'   '3/2/2020 6:01:12 PM',    'N' 
'2','1',    'abc', '3/3/2020 6:01:13  PM'   '3/3/2020 6:01:13 PM',    'N'
'2','2',    'abc', '3/3/2020 6:01:14  PM'   '3/3/2020 6:01:14 PM',    'N'
'3','3',    'abc', '3/3/2020 6:01:15  PM'   '3/3/2020 6:01:15 PM',    'N'
'4','3',    'abc', '3/3/2020 6:01:16  PM'   '3/3/2020 6:01:51 PM',    'N'
'5','3',    'abc', '3/3/2020  6:01:52 PM',  '3/4/2020 4:28:59 PM',    'N'
'6','4',    'abc', '3/4/2020  4:29:00 PM',  '3/4/2020 4:31:40 PM',    'N'
'7','4',    'abc', '3/4/2020  4:31:41 PM',  '12/31/4712',             'Y'
'NULL','5', 'bbc', '3/4/2020 4:31:41  PM'   '3/19/2020 2:47:07 PM',   'N'
'8','6',    'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:47:08 PM'  '3/19/2020 2:50:36 PM',   'N'
'9','7',    'bbc',  '3/19/2020 2:50:37 PM'  '3/20/2020 2:56:23 PM',   'N'
'10','8',   'bbc',  '3/20/2020 2:56:24 PM'  '12/31/4712',             'Y'
```

Comment: (1) Set up a db/sql fiddle of some sort.  (2) What version of Oracle are you using?  (3) What happens if there is a gap in the two tables or if the flags are inconsistent during a period of time?

Comment: Some valid to date has 12/31/4712 this how do you read it ? what is the data type of this valid_to column ?

Comment: 4712 is a year ?

Comment: Hi, yes 4712 is an year. valid_to column is an oracle date field. It is just a default higher end date that we use for the latest record instead of leaving it null. so the valid to_date will have '12/31/4712' until the next change shows up.

Comment: we are using Oracle 12c.  There wont be a gap in both the tables as they are designed in a such a way that date ranges wont have gaps. However, its possible that the time frame may not match for both the tables as in the examples that i gave in that case the key from the table would be null if there is no record for that time frame. the latest_row_flag in the output table is just an indicator to show the latest record for a given id.

Comment: I think you should explain more, because if you see the 1 record of your resut set ie- "'1','NULL', 'abc', '3/2/2020 12:00:00 AM',  '3/2/2020 11:59:59 PM',   'N'"  how did you get this timestamp from ''3/2/2020 11:59:59 PM''?

Comment: So the output table is a super set of both the tables. Meaning,it should include all the distinct valid_from dates from both the tables and the valid_to date should automatically be 1 second less than the next record valid_from date. The challenging part here is to get the appropriate keys from both the tables for all the date ranges in the new table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is what you need:

```sql
with tabs as (
   -- combining both tables: key2 is null for rows from table1 and key1 is null for rows from table2
   select key1,null as key2,ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG from table_1
   union all
   select null,key2,ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG from table_2
)
,time_points as (
   -- using UNPIVOT to get all time points from all intervals from both tables
   select distinct
      id,
      --pt_type,IS_LATEST_FLAG,
      case when pt_type='VALID_FROM' then pt else pt + interval '1' second end as pit
   from (select distinct id,Valid_From, Valid_To,IS_LATEST_FLAG from tabs)
   unpivot (
     pt for pt_type in (Valid_From, Valid_To)
   )
)
,intervals as (
   -- combining time points into intervals:
   select 
     id,row_number()over(partition by id order by pit) rnk
    ,pit as Valid_From
    ,lead(pit)over(partition by id order by pit)-interval '1'second as Valid_To
   from time_points
)
-- main query:
-- simply joining table1 and table2 to our intervals:
select
   i.id,
   i.rnk,
   i.valid_from,
   i.valid_to,
   t1.key1,
   t2.key2,
   least(nvl(t1.is_latest_flag,'N'),nvl(t2.is_latest_flag,'N')) as is_latest_flag
from intervals i
     left join table_1 t1
          on  i.id = t1.id
          and i.valid_from between t1.valid_from and t1.valid_to
     left join table_2 t2
          on  i.id = t2.id
          and i.valid_from between t2.valid_from and t2.valid_to
where i.valid_to is not null
order by i.id,i.valid_from,i.valid_to;
```

Full example with sample data:

```html
with Table_1 (KEY1, ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG) as (
   select '1',    'abc',  to_date('3/2/2020 12:00:00 AM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:12 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '2',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020  6:01:13 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:14 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '3',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020  6:01:15 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:15 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '4',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020  6:01:16 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:51 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '5',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020  6:01:52 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/4/2020 4:28:59 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '6',    'abc',  to_date('3/4/2020  4:29:00 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/4/2020 4:31:40 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '7',    'abc',  to_date('3/4/2020  4:31:41 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('12/31/4712',          'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'Y' from dual union all
   select '8',    'bbc',  to_date('3/19/2020 2:47:08 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/19/2020 2:50:36 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '9',    'bbc',  to_date('3/19/2020 2:50:37 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/19/2020 2:56:23 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'N' from dual union all
   select '10',   'bbc',  to_date('3/19/2020 2:56:24 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('12/31/4712',          'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),  'Y' from dual 
)
,Table_2  (KEY2, ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG) as (
   select '1',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020 12:00:00 AM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:13 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'N' from dual union all
   select '2',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:14  PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:14 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'N' from dual union all
   select '3',    'abc',  to_date('3/3/2020 6:01:15  PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/4/2020 4:28:59 PM', 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'N' from dual union all
   select '4',    'abc',  to_date('3/4/2020 4:29:00  PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('12/31/4712',          'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'Y' from dual union all
   select '5',    'bbc',  to_date('3/4/2020 4:31:41  PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/19/2020 2:47:07 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'N' from dual union all
   select '6',    'bbc',  to_date('3/19/2020 2:47:08 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/19/2020 2:50:36 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'N' from dual union all
   select '7',    'bbc',  to_date('3/19/2020 2:50:37 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('3/20/2020 2:56:23 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'N' from dual union all
   select '8',    'bbc',  to_date('3/20/2020 2:56:24 PM','mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'), to_date('12/31/4712',          'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss AM'),'Y' from dual 
)
,tabs as (
   -- combining both tables: key2 is null for rows from table1 and key1 is null for rows from table2
   select key1,null as key2,ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG from table_1
   union all
   select null,key2,ID,Valid_From, Valid_To, IS_LATEST_FLAG from table_2
)
,time_points as (
   -- using UNPIVOT to get all time points from all intervals from both tables
   select distinct
  id,
  --pt_type,IS_LATEST_FLAG,
  case when pt_type='VALID_FROM' then pt else pt + interval '1' second end as pit
   from (select distinct id,Valid_From, Valid_To,IS_LATEST_FLAG from tabs)
   unpivot (
 pt for pt_type in (Valid_From, Valid_To)
   )
)
,intervals as (
   -- combining time points into intervals:
   select 
 id,row_number()over(partition by id order by pit) rnk
,pit as Valid_From
,lead(pit)over(partition by id order by pit)-interval '1'second as Valid_To
   from time_points
)
-- main query:
-- simply joining table1 and table2 to our intervals:
select
   i.id,
   i.rnk,
   i.valid_from,
   i.valid_to,
   t1.key1,
   t2.key2,
   least(nvl(t1.is_latest_flag,'N'),nvl(t2.is_latest_flag,'N')) as is_latest_flag
from intervals i
 left join table_1 t1
      on  i.id = t1.id
      and i.valid_from between t1.valid_from and t1.valid_to
 left join table_2 t2
      on  i.id = t2.id
      and i.valid_from between t2.valid_from and t2.valid_to
where i.valid_to is not null
order by i.id,i.valid_from,i.valid_to;
```

Results:

```
ID         RNK VALID_FROM          VALID_TO            KEY1  KEY2  IS_LATEST_FL
--- ---------- ------------------- ------------------- ----- ----- ------------
abc          1 2020-03-02 00:00:00 2020-03-02 23:59:59 1           N
abc          2 2020-03-03 00:00:00 2020-03-03 18:01:12 1     1     N
abc          3 2020-03-03 18:01:13 2020-03-03 18:01:13 2     1     N
abc          4 2020-03-03 18:01:14 2020-03-03 18:01:14 2     2     N
abc          5 2020-03-03 18:01:15 2020-03-03 18:01:15 3     3     N
abc          6 2020-03-03 18:01:16 2020-03-03 18:01:51 4     3     N
abc          7 2020-03-03 18:01:52 2020-03-04 16:28:59 5     3     N
abc          8 2020-03-04 16:29:00 2020-03-04 16:31:40 6     4     N
abc          9 2020-03-04 16:31:41 4712-12-31 00:00:00 7     4     Y
bbc          1 2020-03-04 16:31:41 2020-03-19 14:47:07       5     N
bbc          2 2020-03-19 14:47:08 2020-03-19 14:50:36 8     6     N
bbc          3 2020-03-19 14:50:37 2020-03-19 14:56:23 9     7     N
bbc          4 2020-03-19 14:56:24 2020-03-20 14:56:23 10    7     N
bbc          5 2020-03-20 14:56:24 4712-12-31 00:00:00 10    8     Y

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thats nice one!